# Why Material UI Typography element need to be rendered in a client side Nextjs component?

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I am starting a new project with Nextjs 13, and I use material UI to implement the website design.
When I use one of the simplest elements "Typography" with server-side component, the website crashs.

So, I did add "use client" to make it works.

- This works

```
"use client"

import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import * as React from "react";

const AppFooter: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <footer>
      <Typography component="p" className="text-center bg-primary text-secondary">
          This is the website footer.
      </Typography>
    </footer>
  );
}

export default AppFooter;
```

- This doesn't work

```
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import * as React from "react";

const AppFooter: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <footer>
      <Typography component="p" className="text-center bg-primary text-secondary">
          This is the website footer.
      </Typography>
    </footer>
  );
}

export default AppFooter;
```

I want to use material UI elements in the server-side components without using "use client".

Comment: I don't use MUI for my projects, but Igor's answer is the best way to get around the current limitations for the libraries. 

As to the why, per the original question, most of the MUI components use React context and some of hooks to compose themselves. Source code for the Typography component is here.

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/1315abd9c1dcbe1741f142db559b4d7d42532a6b/packages/mui-material/src/Typography/Typography.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a major inconvenience in current MUI version when it comes to using MUI components in Next.js 13 server components. The workaround is to create thin wrappers for every single MUI component that you want to use directly in a server component:

```js
"use client";

import { ComponentProps } from "react";
import TypographyComponent from "@mui/material/Typography";

export default function Typography({
    children,
    ...rest
}: ComponentProps<typeof TypographyComponent>) {
    return <TypographyComponent {...rest}>{children}</TypographyComponent>;
}
```